# 1980’s (or 70’s) show where the main character could teleport by pushing a button on their belt

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a show in the 80’s, could have been originally 70’s. The main character could teleport themselves by pushing a button on their belt.  They would push the button disappear then reappear where they chose.  Anyone know what this show was?

Comment: Was this a male or female character? White? Black? Asian? Alien?

Answer (score 27):

This could be: [The Tomorrow People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People) (1973 - 1979).

(Not to be confused with the 1990s ITV version or the 2013 USTV version.)

A few main characters who were slowly replaced over the eight-season run with Nicholas Young (second from the right) being the only actor to last the whole production run.

They had telekinesis, telepathy, mind-control in a limited fashion, and teleportation ("jaunting"). Their natural abilities were enhanced by the belt-buckle. They also had access to a hidden lab and an advanced computer called Tim - given to them by a representative of a galactic civilisation - which spoke and augmented their powers. Their belts were replaced in the last season by wrist-mounted devices.

Their history - humanity had once been gifted with these powers, but a tyrannical alien civilisation, wishing to hold onto it's power-base had suppressed the abilities technologically. The technology was failing allowing some individuals to "break-out" and gain their inheritance.

A glimpse of their belts can be seen, a rectangular checkerboard fastener (to which they'd clip-on a box) which they'd grip then teleport.

[image: A bunch of actors in cords and jackets grinning at camera]

<sup>Copright uncertain, possibly [Thames Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_Television), 1974 ish. Fair usage.</sup>

The belt with the box affixed can be seen here from season 1 (if I recall correctly). It has a button:

[image: Actors with silly looking belts]

<sup>Copyright Thames Television, 1973. Fair usage. Via [eofftvreview](https://eofftvreview.wordpress.com/2020/11/23/the-tomorrow-people-1973-1979/).</sup>

Comment: Watch out for the 1990s reboot of this, where the characters can teleport without the help of belts - just in case someone looks this up on Youtube and gets the wrong version!

Comment: US versions of British shows don't count :D

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket  Someof the plot elements you mention were not in the 1970s Tomorrow People but where in one or more of the later shows.  The Tomorrow People were the first of a new breed instead of regaining supressed powers which humans once had, and they didn't find a crashed spaceship, but they did have contact with Tomorrow People on various alien worlds.

Comment: @JiminyCricket..  The room was The Lab (underground) and the globe was Tim, the computer they were gifted by the alien federation.  Have a look at the first paragraph of "Original Series" in the wikipedia entry you link to.  And they could jaunt (teleport) without the belt but it provided stability & extra distance

Comment: Why does this remind me of Power Rangers?